# Specify which database to use in mongodb .js script

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I just want to run a .js script against a particular mongodb database, but can't seem to get the correct syntax.

```
echo "print(db.address.find().limit(1));" > test.js
mongo test.js
```

How do I select the database that this will be executed on, I've tried various combinations of `use foo` with no success.

```
> show dbs                      
admin   (empty)
local   (empty)
foo 0.203125GB
bar 0.203125GB
```

I would like to use `foo` in this case.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
mongo <name of db> --eval "db.runCommand( <js in here> );"
```

Or if you dont have a specific runCommand script, you can just do:

```
mongo <name of db> --eval "<js in here>;"
```

If you are using a return value:

```
mongo <name of db> --eval "db.eval('return fnName()')"
```

For a file

```
mongo <name of db> some_instructions.js
```

Comment: How can I specify a file? ie not put a lump of javascript in that command line function?

Comment: Remember that double quotes in bash will treat `$` (and [some other characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)) as special characters! So you should either use single quotes (`'<js in here>'`) or escape `$` and other special characters with a backslash: `mongo mydbname --eval "JSON.stringify( db.mycollectionname.find({count: {\$lte:1} }).limit(2).toArray() )"` It may be worth changing the quotes in your answer to single quotes, Chris?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `db.getSiblingDB()` method, as mentioned [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/mongodb/mongo-script) and in the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB).

```
// Equivalent for "use <db>" command in mongo shell
db = db.getSiblingDB('foo')
```

This is particularly useful when writing scripts using the mongo shell where the `use` helper is not available. Or when you cannot refer to the DB on the connection string.